# IPA transported to App Store Connect isn't showing up

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have just updated an app for iOS/iPadOS. The .ipa file is ready to upload to my App Store Connect entry for the app - previous versions have been deployed over the past few years.

I built the app using CB 11.1 on Windows 11. I am also using a Mac Mini running MacOS Monterey 12.1, Xcode 13.2.1.

I have copied the .ipa file to the Mac Mini, started the Transporter (v 1.2.4) and dragged my .ipa file onto the Transporter. I received a message saying the file was successfully uploaded.

Many hours later (16+), this build still hasn't appeared in the App Store Connect entry for the app so that I can submit it for review. What have I missed (i.e., what has changed since my last submission in January 2022)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's either an Apple support issue, or you've been mistaken about what you uploaded. Either way, this question is off-topic, here. Open Transporter and double check *exactly* what you uploaded.

Comment: Dave, Thanks for the response - it was a valuable data point. You are correct, it seemed to be an Apple issue, not a C++ Builder issue. I resubmitted the .ipa to Transporter this morning and all went well. Very strange, but the app has been accepted.